# how to block text selection without input textarea and select items

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, select, input, textarea

How to block text selection without input textarea and select items
i actually have the script that works in IE but not in other browsers, here it is:

```
 var omitformtags=["input", "textarea", "select"]
 omitformtags=omitformtags.join("|")
 function disableselect(e){
  if (omitformtags.indexOf(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase())==-1)
   return false
  }
 function reEnable(){
   return true
  }

 if (typeof document.onselectstart!="undefined")
  document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false")
 else{
  document.onmousedown=disableselect
  document.onmouseup=reEnable
 }
  document.onmousedown=click;
  function click()
 {
  if ((event.button==2) || (event.button==3)) { alert("Yazı Kopyalayamazsınız!");}

 }
```

i need to work it the same way in other browsers, there must be a ready script, just couldnt find in net..

Comment: so what do you mean by your question

Comment: i need to block the same way on other browsers isnt it obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div onmousedown='return false;' onselectstart='return false;'></div>
```

onmousedown disables the selection for Firefox, Safari, Opera, Chrome and most other web browsers, onselectstart for IE.

Though disabling text selection and context menus is very bad style and does not prevent the pro-users from selecting your text. Simply disabling JavaScript in their browsers enables the selection again.

Comment: The question isn't about divs, but about inputs. This works for divs - for me - but not for inputs. Is there a way to do this for inputs?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated my answer to be more clear**:

browsers can disable selecting using css styles or using special element attribute. This way is better:

- no script to support
- no fear that user disables script and copies content she needs
- elegant solution

Opera and IE ignores such a style, but there is html element attribute unselectable, which denies selecting. Try the following page (I tested in IE8, FF3.6, Safari5, opera11, Chrome8):

```
<html>

<head>

<style>

.unselectable {
    -moz-user-select: none; /* for FireFox */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* for Chrome and Safari */
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* probably old webkit browsers, but new support it too */
    user-select: none; /* for future CSS3 compliant browsers */
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<!-- add unselectable class to deny selecting in FF, Chrome, Safari and CSS3 compliant browsers -->
<!-- add unselectable attribute to deny selecting in Opera and IE -->
<div class="unselectable" unselectable="on">test</div>

</body>

</html>
```

For additional information about it visit [this page](http://help.dottoro.com/lcrlukea.php). Now you can pick best option for you to use/mantain. One more time - this solution does not need javascript at all and should be imho more safe (if you can edit html\css pages and don't need dynamic. otherwise you can try to add css class\element attribute through javascript..)

Comment: what a pain.  there really should be a way to say "allow input and textarea field contents to be selected, otherwise don't allow selections on other elements".  i don't care if advanced users can still get to text.  what I care about is that in drag and drop type UIs especially I don't want non-input elements getting selected.  seems reasonable, but somehow its very difficult to achieve.

Comment: well but as the javascript solution you can modify the css with the chrome inspector simple to inspect the element check the class "unselectable" and remove it... as the javascript solution this doesn't work for developers and serious advances users... :S lol...

Comment: The question isn't about divs, but about inputs. This works for divs - for me - but not for inputs.

Comment: Looking at your link, user-select is not supported by inputs. So this is a bummer :(