# How to make Chrome input unselectable (but allow editing)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, cross-browser

Code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.ctrl = function(key, callback) {
    if(typeof key != 'object') key = [key];
    callback = callback || function(){ return false; }
    return $(this).keydown(function(e) {
        var ret = true;
        $.each(key,function(i,k){
            if(e.keyCode == k.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) && e.ctrlKey) {
                ret = callback(e);
            }
        });
        return ret;
    });
};


$.fn.disableSelection = function() {
    $(window).ctrl(['a','s','c']);
    return this.each(function() {           
        $(this).attr('unselectable', 'on')
               .css({'-moz-user-select':'none',
                    '-o-user-select':'none',
                    '-khtml-user-select':'none',
                    '-webkit-user-select':'none',
                    '-ms-user-select':'none',
                    'user-select':'none'})
               .each(function() {
                    $(this).attr('unselectable','on')
                    .bind('selectstart',function(){ return false; });
               });
    });
};

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("textarea").on('focus',function(){
        $(this).disableSelection();
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EBhya/8/

The idea behind it is that the user can type, but cannot highlight text.  Changes and such can still be made with arrow keys and what not.

On Firefox and IE, this works **100%** as desired.

On Chrome, and probably on Safari, the input is disabled when you focus on it and you cannot even type.

I have tried everything from waiting until `keydown` to apply the disabled selection, to trying to monitor the mouse clicks and selection.  Anyway, if anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe a totally different approach will do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4656495/825789

Comment: whatever it is you are trying to do, could cause some issues on tablets/phones

Comment: @bfavaretto this works perfectly.  Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to block text selection without input textarea and select items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655541/how-to-block-text-selection-without-input-textarea-and-select-items)

Comment: I'm marking the question as a duplicate of that other one, okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As bfavaretto suggested, this here does the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4656495/825789